# Length recommendation of safety spotters for a home gym

Tags: exercise-equipment, safety

When planning my new home gym I stumbled over the question of how long safety spotters should be. For example the kingsbox royal series seems to be a reasonable option to me but has only 51 cm safety [spotters](https://www.kingsbox.it/en/product/royal-angel-arms/?force_switch=1). I am not sure if this is enough.

So is there any rule of what is a good length of safety spotters and why?

Comment: I'm assuming you're planning on using this for bench press, do you plan on using it for squats too (or do you just bail the lift)?

Comment: Yes I want to use it for squats too.